# "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" in server only but it is working fine in my local system

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

This is the code to insert datetime into sql server 2008 using c#. This same code is working fine in my local system but it is not working in server some times.please see the code mentioned below and let me know your answers and suggestions

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ad;
    btnupdate.Visible = false;
    btnactive1.Visible = false;
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        //getting length of uploaded file
        int length = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        //create a byte array to store the binary image data
        byte[] imgbyte = new byte[length];
        //store the currently selected file in memeory
        HttpPostedFile img = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
        //set the binary data
        string area = ddlarea.SelectedItem.Text;
        string cat = ddlcategory.SelectedItem.Text;
        string subcat = ddlsubcategory.SelectedItem.Text;
        string head = txthead.Text;
        string subhead = txtsubhead.Text;
        string shortdesc = txtshortdesc.Text;
        string url = txturl.Text;
        //string imagename = txtimagename.Text;
        string regdate = txtregdate.Text;
        string expirydate = txtexpirydate.Text;
        string customername = txtcustomername.Text;
        string contact = txtcontact.Text;
        string email = txtemail.Text;
        if (CheckBox2.Checked == true)
        {
            ad = "paid ad";
        }
        else
        {
            ad = "free ad";
        }
        img.InputStream.Read(imgbyte, 0, length);
        con = new SqlConnection(str);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_paid_ads (area,catagory,subcatagory,heading,subheading,shortdescription,url,imagedata,dateofregistration,dateofexpiry,customername,contactno,email,ad) values (@area,@cat,@subcat,@head,@subhead,@shortdesc,@url,@imagedata,@regdate,@expirydate,@customername,@contact,@email,@ad)", con);
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_paid_ads (image_name,image) values (@imagename,@imagedata)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@area", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = area;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cat", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = cat;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@subcat", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = subcat;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@head", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = head;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@subhead", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = subhead;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@shortdesc", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1000).Value = shortdesc;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@url", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = url;
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagename", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = imagename;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagedata", SqlDbType.Image).Value = imgbyte;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@regdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = regdate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@expirydate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = expirydate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@customername", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = customername;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@contact", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = contact;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = email;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ad", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = ad;
        int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        if (count == 1)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Paid Ad added successfully')</script>");
        }
        resetpaidad();
    }
}
```

Comment: codelayout is supported in markup... give it a try...and check and compare the regional settings on your local box and your sever...

Comment: what format is your date? dd.mm.yyyy ? mm.dd.yyyy? maybe system try to  save 21 as month. you should not adding date into string.

Comment: @pintu. Where did `btnupdate` come from? I don't see that anywhere in the original code?

Comment: format is dd/MM/yyyy in my system.can you please tell me how to do without adding date to string??

Comment: Your paramters are `DateTime`, but you getting the values from TextBoxes, which are strings.

Answer (score 1):

The user interface (UI) should be validating that the date is in a specific format, then you need to convert the `string` to a `DateTime`. For example, if the UI date format is `DD/MM/YYYY` you should replace this line...

```
string expirydate = txtexpirydate.Text;
```

with...

```
DateTime expirydate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtexpirydate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And the same for `regdate`.

Note: the above will work if the date format of the text box is always fixed. But if the UI validation enforces different formats in different locations you will need to get the date format currently used by the UI which may be dependent on the locale where the UI is running.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
string regdate = txtregdate.Text;
string expirydate = txtexpirydate.Text;
```

Try this:

```
Datetime regdate =  DateTime.ParseExact(txtregdate.Text, "M-d-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime expirydate =  DateTime.ParseExact( txtexpirydate.Text, "M-d-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

assuming your textbox contains date in format: M-d-yyyy, change it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

THe way to avoid this is to set the SqlDbType of the parameter and, when assigning the parameter value, *cast* the client-side value to the CLR type that maps to the SqlDbType.